# Cannot change product in draft picking (TypeError: d.error is undefined) in Odoo 10c

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, odoo-10, odoo-view

Impacted versions: Odoo10c

Steps to reproduce:

```
i am using demo database
go to menu Inventory/All Transfers
create new picking, choose any picking type (I choose delivery order)
input items
Save
click Edit
choose one of items and change to other product
```

Current behavior:
if using Google Chrome, It will raise error warning Error: QWeb2 - template['CrashManager.warning']: Runtime Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
if using Firefox, error will become TypeError: d.error is undefined

Expected behavior:
no error

Video/Screenshot link (optional):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue on my older version of Odoo10.

Try with updated revision of Odoo10 and error will gone.